# DebugKit CakePHP 3.x ReferenceError: __debug_kit_id is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, apache, sqlite, cakephp-3.0

I recently upgraded php from 5.6 to 7 and I think it broke CakePHP's DebugKit.  On every page I navigate to within my app, the debug_kit javascript file produces an error, specifically when setting the currentRequest.  The error is:

> **ReferenceError: __debug_kit_id is not defined**

At first I didn't install sqlite, so I thought that was the issue, but after installing the sqlite, mbstring, and intl extensions the error is still there.  I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, most of the problems people encounter with debugkit seem to be solved by installing sqlite.

The code snippet from the debug_kit.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    toolbar = new Toolbar({
    button: $('#toolbar'),
    content: $('#panel-content-container'),
    panelButtons: $('.panel'),
    panelClose: $('#panel-close'),
    keyboardScope : $(document),
    currentRequest: __debug_kit_id,
    originalRequest: __debug_kit_id,
    baseUrl: __debug_kit_base_url
});

toolbar.initialize();
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This not appear to be a PHP error, but rather a Javascript one because the variable `__debug_kit_id` is not defined anywhere in your Javascript code. Define it to be something like

```
var __debug_kit_id = 0;
```

or whatever value it should have and that will solve your error.

Comment: That would get rid of this specific JavaScript error, but wouldn't get the DebugKit working again.  It is definitely PHP related, despite the error being thrown from the js file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem by removing all remaining php5 packages.  I followed bento's answer from this askubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-compelety-remove-php and going one by one through the old php5 packages (leaving php7 packages intact).  Thanks all